# Finding a value by key in nested JSON (io.vertx.core.json)

Tags: java, json, java-stream, vert.x

I have a nested JSON like this which I stored in a `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject`.

```
{
    "field1" : [],
    "field2" : "value1",
    "field3" : [],
    "field4" : [{
        "field5" : "value2",
        "field6" : {
            "date" : "2021-04-27"
        }
    }]
}
```

I want to use Stream API and find the "value2" using key "field5".

I tried to use it like this but it always returns to me null value. It's a key at 2nd level

```
Optional<Map.Entry<String, Object>> result =
    myJsonObject.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getKey().contains("field5"))
                .findAny();
```

But if I use the above line for any key at 1st level (field1, field2, field3), it returns with its value correctly.

I'm using io.vertx.core.json and can only use this library.

Comment: What type is source `myJsonObject`?

Comment: I'd assume that ` myJsonObject.stream()` creates a stream for only that specific object (or level) and to get to nested objects/levels you'd need to `flatMap()` their streams.

Comment: What kind of Json library are you using? Is it standard org.json?

Comment: Essential information (what is myJsonObject) is not contained, so no meaningful answer can be given.

Comment: Updated my question with the used library. I can use this library only.

Answer (score 0):

### com.google.gson

Edit: [Solution based on io.vertx.core.json package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69114196/11139208)
*(I would like to preserve this post to show the main idea.)*

#### The main idea

I don't know which library you use, so I choose GSON ([GitHub](https://github.com/google/gson), [API](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.8/com.google.gson/module-summary.html), [Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)).

I find the [class hierarchy of com.google.gson](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.8/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/package-tree.html) clear and reasonable:
`JsonElement` extends `java.lang.Object`, and its subclasses are: `JsonArray`, `JsonNull`, `JsonObject` and `JsonPrimitive`. Pretty straighforward.

Well, this structure brings us a good hint.
Your JSON is something like this:

```
{
  "field1" : JsonArray,
  "field2" : JsonPrimitive,
  "field3" : JsonArray,
  "field4" : JsonArray
}
```

...or even like this:

```
{
  "field1" : JsonElement,
  "field2" : JsonElement,
  "field3" : JsonElement,
  "field4" : JsonElement
}
```

So you can reach any key / value from the first level quite easily. The deeper levels are encapsulated. You say OK, extract them. However, there is a question:

Does the structure contain additional meaning, that you want to preserve?

If not, simply make it flat, as Thomas suggests it.
If that matters, traverse through the JSON.
(I don't know your choice, so I just collect values.)

#### Without Stream API

I wrote a very simple method which traverses and collects (into a static `java.util.List`) every value of a specified key:

```java
//...
  private static void traverseAndCollectByKey(JsonElement jsonElement, String key) {
    if (jsonElement instanceof JsonObject) {
      JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

      if (jsonObject.has(key)) {
        results.add(jsonObject.get(key));
      }
      jsonObject.entrySet().forEach(
          entry -> traverseAndCollectByKey(entry.getValue(), key));
      
    } else if (jsonElement instanceof JsonArray) {
      jsonElement.getAsJsonArray().forEach(e -> traverseAndCollectByKey(e, key));
    }
  }
//...
```

#### With Stream API

`recursiveFlattening` is simple mapper function, but it calls itself to reach any depth.

```java
//...
  private static Stream<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> recursiveFlattening(
      Entry<String, JsonElement> entry) {

    JsonElement jsonElement = entry.getValue();

    if (jsonElement instanceof JsonObject) {
      return jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .flatMap(Main::recursiveFlattening);

    } else if (jsonElement instanceof JsonArray) {
      JsonArray jsonArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();

      return IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.size())
                      .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry("", jsonArray.get(i)))
                      .flatMap(Main::recursiveFlattening);

    } else {
      return Stream.of(entry);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Let's use them

```java
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


class Main {
  private static final String jsonString =
      "{"
          + "\"field1\" : [],"
          + "\"field2\" : \"value1\","
          + "\"field3\" : [],"
          + "\"field4\" : [{"
          + "  \"field5\" : \"value2\","
          + "  \"field6\" : {"
          + "    \"date\" : \"2021-04-27\""
          + "  }"
          + "  }]"
          + "}";

  private static final List<JsonElement> results = new ArrayList<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();

    traverseAndCollectByKey(jsonObject, "field5");

    results.forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("-".repeat(10));

    jsonObject.entrySet().stream()
                         .flatMap(Main::recursiveFlattening)
                         .filter(e -> "field5".equals(e.getKey()))
                         .map(Entry::getValue)
                         .forEach(System.out::println);


    // In your case:
    Optional<Map.Entry<String, Object>> result =
        myJsonObject.stream()
                    .flatMap(Main::recursiveFlattening)
                    .filter(e -> "field5".equals(e.getKey()))
                    .findAny();
  }
//...
```

Playable demo: https://replit.com/@huzz4/Traverse-and-collect-from-JSON-comgooglegson

Comment: I updated my question with the used library. I can use the mentioned library only. Also I only want to extract a single values. It could reside in any level.

Comment: @Aman I post a solution based on io.vertx.core.json package. I keep this one to show the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

### io.vertx.core.json

I altered my [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69109193/11139208) to be compatible with `io.vertx.core.json` package.

###### The main changes:

`com.google.gson.JsonElement` -> `java.lang.Object`
`jsonElement.getAsJsonObject()` -> `(JsonObject) jsonElement`
`jsonElement.getAsJsonArray()` -> `(JsonArray) jsonElement`

#### Without Stream API

`io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject` implements `Iterable<Map.Entry<String, Object>>`, so I can use `forEach` on it.

```java
//...
  private static void traverseAndCollectByKey(Object jsonElement, String key) {
    if (jsonElement instanceof JsonObject) {
      JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonElement;

      if (jsonObject.containsKey(key)) {
        results.add(jsonObject.getValue(key));
      }
      jsonObject.forEach(entry -> traverseAndCollectByKey(entry.getValue(), key));

    } else if (jsonElement instanceof JsonArray) {
      ((JsonArray) jsonElement).forEach(item -> traverseAndCollectByKey(item, key));
    }
  }
//...
```

#### With Stream API

`io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject` and `io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray` also has `stream` method, so this function simplified a bit:

```java
//...
  private static Stream<Map.Entry<String, Object>> recursiveFlattening(
      Entry<String, Object> entry) {

    Object jsonElement = entry.getValue();

    if (jsonElement instanceof JsonObject) {
      return ((JsonObject) jsonElement).stream()
                                       .flatMap(Main::recursiveFlattening);

    } else if (jsonElement instanceof JsonArray) {
      return ((JsonArray) jsonElement).stream()
                                      .map(v -> Map.entry("", v))
                                      .flatMap(Main::recursiveFlattening);

    } else {
      return Stream.of(entry);
    }
  }
}
```

Playable demo: https://replit.com/@huzz4/Traverse-and-collect-from-JSON-iovertxcorejson

##### Solution with recursiveFlattening

```java
Optional<Map.Entry<String, Object>> result =
    myJsonObject.stream()
                .flatMap(Main::recursiveFlattening)
                .filter(e -> "field5".equals(e.getKey()))
                .findAny();
```